# Testing VSCode using Postman

Tags: visual-studio-code, postman

I'm following Ian Munro's 1702-express-review videos on YouTube as part of my training for work. I have never used Postman before. I need to somehow link my VSCode to Postman but am not sure how.

What I've done so far:

- Installed Postman Runner as an extension on VSCode.
- Created and started coding my project on VSCode.

Apparently I need to "Export my Postman collections and environments in a folder (or subfolder) and open it with VSCode". How do I do this?

Comment: Why do you want to do it ?

Comment: Have you actually looked at the documentation for `Postman Runner for VSCode` ? There is a short explainer on how to export collections and environments at the bottom here : https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eridem.vscode-postman

Answer (score 0):

Just press `Control+Q`

Now select :

1. collection file
2. Environment file
3. Iteration count, delay , data file etc

But , using vscode for postman will just make your life harder. Use postman native app for coding .

If you are looking for a way to format the code . Just press `ctrl+b` in postman app to format the code correctly